# How do I effectively jungle as Gangplank?

Tags: league-of-legends

Every time I try him, I end up falling behind.

My masteries are 21/9/0 and I have offensive runes: 3x Armor Pen & 6x flat dmg reds / 9x armor yellows / 9x mana per 5 blues / 3 dmg quints.

I don't see those 50% dmg Parley's ( Q ).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Starting Items: Either I start with base safe jungling cloth/5 pots or Vampiric Scepter but post-nerf when I get to 4 I go back to base to get full hp to start Ganks

Also, I keep running out of mana if I try to Q every minion to get more gold per creep.

Comment: He got nerfed hard. Him losing the ability to stack his passive 5 times hurt him on multiple camps in terms of seconds and damage taken. He's a far better top laner.

Comment: What is your starting item? Does your team give you a good leash? Be a little more descriptive and I can try to help you :D

Answer (score 1):

This start works fairly decent for every physical attack based jungler:

Items:

1. Cloth Armor, 5 HP pots.
2. Run through some camps (will mention the route later), and buy yourself a Madred's Razor
3. Keep running through camps, feel free to gank or at least shoot off a parrrley or two to help out the lanes, and keep running around until you have boots (They usually depend on the enemy team)
4. Run around camps some more until you have you have upgraded boots and a Wriggle

(Item priority order: Razor -> Boots 1 -> Wriggle -> Boots 2)

That pretty much creates a solid start for any jungler. Past that, feel free to build in what ever way you want. (that obviously being an Atmogs, Yoummu and Infinity, and maybe a Phantom)

Route:

This one is if the enemy has a jungler:

1. Your Wolves
2. Your Blue
3. Your Wraiths
4. Your Small Golems
5. Your Your Red
6. Your Wraiths
7. Your Wolves
8. Teleport Back

This one is if the enemy DOESNT have a jungler (and is something i came up with without any external help):

1. Their Blue
2. Their Wolves
3. Your Wraiths
4. Your Small Golems
5. Your Red
6. Your wolves (when you take this camp out, tell your mid to pick up Your Blue)
7. Your Blue (To mid)
8. Their Wraiths
9. Their Small Golems
10. Teleport (Save Their Red for when you got yer entire fit)

I havent used this route for a while tho, so i cant remember when you should pick up a Madred's Razor, but do it as soon as you have gold for it.

Masteries should be 21/9, focusing on physicals in the offense tree, and armor in the defense.

As for runes, Armor Yellows, MagRes/lvl blues. For reds, depending on what you want, either some crit runes, or ArPen for the jungling. For the quints, ArPen, Crit runes or Gold/10 runes (switch out your Defense masteries for utility masteries for full benefit of G/10).

Answer (score 0):

When I jungle with Gangplank, I go 3 dmg / 9dmg red / 9armor yellow / 9mana regen per 5 blue

And i max my Q first to last hit minions and to counter jungle wraiths spawn, and its good to gank with it maxed..!

Comment: I go max E for faster faster attackdmg and movement speed... gonna try Q first

Comment: trying it now... works wonders... although AP casters are blowing me...

Comment: @Tura, lol not sure "blowing me" is really the best choice of words.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the basic runes, my preferred strategy with jungle gangplank is to start boots/3 pots because my focus is more on ganking.

Early GP ganks are absolutely broken. Lvl 1 champions have no chance against your slow and parley if you manage to catch them with your lane partner. Once you have red, you have a double slow that boots also help capitalize on.

Comment: thanks i thought of that but lately I run out of luck with laners... all are "Come gank my lane" and i get there and they recall... its dumb

Comment: But thanks everything helps out

Answer (score 0):

Gangplank is a jungler that can gank well but benefits more form farming. So I suggest you get 1 gp10 item and farm the jungel ganking only where it is mostly needed. Besides You can help your team even while farming using ult. After mid games comes around split push much as you can with gangplank then you will be a late game beast! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Things to keep in mind: `GP is an extremely slow jungle, extremely mana hungry and overall there are much better choices.` However, if you're like me, you find him extremely fun and are willing to take the slow start that powerballs into an extremely powerful squishy annihilator.

I roll with 3xLifesteal quints, armor pen reds or AD reds depending on enemy team, armor yellows and scaling magic resist glyphs. I prefer scaling magic resist for late game viability, and I only pick GP jungle when my mid won't need blue. (Kennen, for example) The lifesteal quints I feel are very important, it provides just enough sustain in the jungle to successfully clear. My mastery page is [standard AD/tank](http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/mastery-tree-planner#&tree1=1-3-0-0-4-0-0-4-1-0-0-1-3-0-3-0-1&tree2=0-1-3-0-4-0-0-1-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0&tree3=0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0&v=2). My starting items are usually cloth armor and 5 health pots so I can safely gank and clear without having to B, however, you can go boots/3 health pots if you want to gank after blue and then go back and buy, or you can go with a vamp scepter if you don't plan on ganking much or your lanes are going to pushed. Cloth armor/5 pots is usually a much safer choice. I get my E first, then Q, then W, then rank up Q.

I start blue (don't use smite) -> wolves -> red (use smite) -> gank (usually top, sometimes mid if over extended; very rarely bottom unless I know they don't have wards)

GP ganks are absolutely lethal, you land a parrrley and you're either going to force a summoner or get a kill. When you come out to gank, whenever possible save your E for when your lane champion is in range so you both get the benefit; this will make a huge difference.

The first item I rush is a Madred's, then boots, then philo stone, then wriggle's. In between I will usually buy a ward for top lane (river bush or tribush) and enemy wraiths. Knowing the enemy jungler's location lets you safely counter jungle, safely gank, or counter gank; it can really secure a win.

Beyond philo and wriggles items are situational, but you should be out of laning phase by this point. If you can safely dragon squeeze those in, don't be afraid to use your ult to save a tower and keep wards out!

Comment: Um... here's a few tips for yourself: If you get a leash on the wolves, you can clear them out and be at blue very soon. 2nd, use smite on blue, then go wraiths, small golems, and you will have smite ready again at red.

Comment: @ChaosPointDK That really slows down your gank route. Flash will almost always be burned on your ganks if you're doing it right, so gank early and burn flash so you can come back and gank successfully after your full clear. Wolves also shouldn't be leashed for you; if you're going to do them, you should tank them and have them damage them. It's fine to do if you're playing with people smart enough to do it right and not accidentally take a kill and screw your xp, but more often than not in lower and norms it only screws you.

Comment: Not to create an argument, but are you saying that leashing wolves is bad because there is a risk that you are asking a moron? That's not a viable argument at all :p